# How to set the Date Format for CombinedXYChart in AChartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I can set the date format in the time chart like this

```
final GraphicalView view = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset,
                mRenderer, "dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

**but I can't do the same in the case of ComninedXYChart**

```
String[] types = new String[] { TimeChart.TYPE , ScatterChart.TYPE, ScatterChart.TYPE};
final GraphicalView view = 
    ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer, types);
```

**image below:**
[image]

**any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

In the CombinedXYChart case, you will have to use custom labels:

```
// disable the default labels
renderer.setXLabels(0);
// add several such labels
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "label");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found  much better approach. The trick is to use method setXLabelFormat combined with overloaded NumberFormat:

```
 SimpleDateFormat mDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM");
 renderer.setXLabelFormat(new NumberFormat() {
        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(double value, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
            return mDateFormatter.format(value, buffer, field);
        }

        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(long value, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
            return mDateFormatter.format(value, buffer, field);
        }

        @Override
        public Number parse(String string, ParsePosition position) {
            return mDateFormatter.parse(string, position).getTime();
        }
    });
```

Of course it would much bettter if method setXLabelFormat accepted [Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Format.html) (which is base class of all formats) instead of [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html), however i think it is still elegant and quite simple sollution.