# How to set Date Format for X -Axis for CombinedXYChart in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

i want to create a CombinedXYChartIntent, but i need the date format in the x Axis.
I know how to make a simple TimeChartIntent.

```
  Intent intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "HH:mm");
```

**but I can't do the same in the case of ComninedXYChart**

I have read the following entry, but the way he has resolved it, does not work.
There is no method setXLabelFormat() in the class XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.

[How to set the Date Format for CombinedXYChart in AChartEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320739/how-to-set-the-date-format-for-combinedxychart-in-achartengine)

I have basically exactly the same problem, maybe someone has found a way to set Date Format for X -Axis for CombinedXYChart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already found myself a solution, and would like to introduce to you my solution approach.

```
public class LineGraph extends AbstractDemoChart {
      private static final long HOUR = 3600 * 1000;
      private static final long DAY = HOUR * 24;
      private static final int HOURS = 24;

    public Intent getIntent(Context context,double[] personCount, Date[] timeValue) {

        //Create XYSeries, fill it with 24 int Values for X-Axis and PersonCount for Y-Axis
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");
        for (int i = 0; i < timeValue.length; i++) {
            series.add(i, personCount[i]);
        }
        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset =new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        // Now I create the Series renderer
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer =new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        /*last step, Creating the renderer that controls the full charts and add the   single renderer for each series */
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer =new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // Use DateFormatter for having X Labels in the form of HH:mm
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        for (int i = 0; i < timeValue.length; i++) {
            // add custom Labels with correct format
            if(i%2==0){
                mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, formatter.format(timeValue[i]));     
            }
        }
        mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        // disable the default labels
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        mRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Persons");


        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer,  new String[]{BarChart.TYPE},
                    "Weather parameters");
        return intent;
    }
```

after doing this, my X-Axis has time Values in form of HH:mm

I hope this helps you further